# AS3: Stop links opening in new window

Tags: actionscript-3, hyperlink

The links I have in my .swf keep opening in new windows/tabs rather than the same one, how can I make it open in the same tab? Here's my actionscript 3 script:

```
aquaheal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2);
function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(
        new URLRequest("http://www.mediwales.com/index.php?id=6&member=9"), "_self");
}
```

Comment: It should work as is. Are you sure that this exact code is executing?

Comment: Yep, copied and pasted from my script. Just can't understand why it's opening in a new window!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try omitting the `_self` parameter from `navigateToUrl`. It defaults to `null` which is what I believe you want.</strike>

It appears that it is indeed `_self` that you require.

Have you tried running your page on the web rather than from file? The docs say:

> When code in a SWF file that is running in the local-with-filesystem sandbox calls the navigateToURL() function and specifies a custom window name for the window parameter, the window name is transfered into a random name. The name is in the form "_flashXXXXXXXX", where each X represents a random hexadecimal digit. Within the same session (until you close the containing browser window), if you call the function again and specify the same name for the window parameter, the same random string is used.

Maybe this is messing things up for you?

Comment: That is what I had originally and it was opening in a new window/tab, hence adding the _self, which didn't work either.

Comment: Yep it's running on the web, this would've been a 1min job if it was AS2!!

Comment: have you tried with target=_parent already have an issue like this one, my .swf was inside a HTML frame...